# anyway to configure a URL prefix for prestosql web UI

Tags: presto, trino

Given prestosql cluster started and listens to `localhost:8080`, I found it redirects request to `http://localhost:8080/ui/`

```
> curl -v http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
> Accept: */*
> Referer: 
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
< Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2020 14:07:10 GMT
< Location: http://localhost:8080/ui/
< Content-Length: 0
```

Is there anyway to support a prefix like `/prestosql` so that it can redirect request from `/prestosql` to `/prestosql/ui` instead of `/ui/`?

The scenario is about using a gateway in front of prestosql then routing requests via URL rewrite. E.g., Nginx/HAProxy or Istio virtual service.

Comment: No, but I would expect this is something you can do in your proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible and would require quite some work, since Presto's UI HTML and javascript code and expects various resources available at `/ui/...` path.

See previous discussion at https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/3706

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess it will need to expose both `/ui` and `/v1` when proxy prestosql